Storage Partitioning Issue in nested iframe
My use case is depicted below:
We have an extension that, when a PDF URL is loaded, inserts an iframe containing our web-accessible resource (an extension HTML page). This page then creates another iframe that loads our React application hosted on a domain, such as https://example.com/index.html.
When a user opens a PDF URL, like https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample.pdf, two iframes are embedded in the page—the first being our extension page and the second being our React application. These two iframes communicate with each other via postMessage.
To explain further: If I open a PDF, like https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample.pdf, the top-level site (PDF URL) is dynamic. We then insert our iframe (web_accessible_resource), i.e., (chrome-extension://id/viewer.html). Inside this, we load a nested iframe URL of CDN. So, there will be two nested iframes—one for chrome-extension:///index.html and another for https://example.com/index.html. (this is our hosted cdn)
Q1: Due to storage partitioning applied to my CDN, a new service worker is registered each time a new PDF is opened (since each PDF URL is treated as a distinct domain). Cache storage is also being partitioned, preventing reuse across PDF sessions. Additionally, all other storage mechanisms are partitioned, meaning I cannot access the same stored values when a PDF from a different domain is opened. How can I make these storages unpartitioned?
Q2: The HTTP cache is also partitioned, causing a network request every time a new PDF is opened.
How can we address this? Is there an existing API to manage the HTTP cache, or can you suggest a way to make it unpartitioned?
Architecture Reference
I have tried using Storage Access API  but this solution is not practical as it would require user gesture and also show a popup(on each new top level domain).
